# nodejs on mac error when connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, wamp, mamp

This code works well on windows using nodejs and wamp but dont work on mac using mamp any idea why ? (the same username,password and db are used on both mac and pc !)

Im receiving this error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var TEST_DATABASE = 'krekib';
var TEST_TABLE = 'users';
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'root',
  password: '12345',
});


client.query('USE '+TEST_DATABASE);

client.query(
  'SELECT * FROM '+TEST_TABLE,
  function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log(results);
    console.log(fields);
    client.end();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to specify your host and port.  Check which port mysql is running in MAMP and add this.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var TEST_DATABASE = 'krekib';
var TEST_TABLE = 'users';
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'root',
  password: '12345',
  host: "127.0.0.1 or localhost, depends on your mysql user permissions", 
  port: "your port number in mamp",
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Why would you connect to a database with JavaScript? It's really easy to find the JavaScript file and get your username + password.

Is the database running in Mamp?

Comment: I didn't understand your question but what im trying to to do is creating live notification using websocket I/O in a cakephp project !

Comment: Well if found the solution go to mamp server interface click on MYSQL and uncheck allow local connection only .... restart the server and everything should work well !

Comment: The JS isn't exposed since it's Node and running on the server.